# Creating 100m Buffer From coastline inward, for administrative municipalities in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, buffer, overlay, administrative-boundaries

I am attempting to create a 100m Buffer from the coastline inward for the entire perimeter of Jamaica.

I will be overlaying Landsat images over an administrative shapefiles. My end goal is to do analysis of the beaches for each administrative t seems like I need to add a feature demarcating the land and the sea as a start, and I have not figured out how to do so accurately.

What is the most effective way to demarcate the land and sea, for the eventual creation of a buffer?

[image: Image from Administrative Shapefile of Jamaica]

Comment: Dissolve the admin area polygons into a single large polygon that you can convert into a boundary polyline suitable for negative buffering.

Comment: Maybe you can use the OSM coastline dataset from https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/coastlines.html as a start?

Comment: I'd use another (coarse) boundary line dataset, select for all polygons within 10-20 km of the coast, then dissolve that (way faster and less likely to have topology problems before dissolving). Then you can use the outer ring for your 100m buffer.